# Automation returning an empty array on executing an XPATH

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, webdriver, ui-automation

I am writing an automation where I want my webdriver to click on the dropdown icon. 
I took the xpath of the icon where I want webdriver to click, I tested the xpath in chrome console,  it works fine !!

but when I run my automation, it returns me an empty array and fails.

Array []

Any hints why and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Please reread the question and imagine yourself in our shoes - is it clear how to help here?

Comment: just reframed it ...let me know if I can provide you with more info.

Comment: Actually it is impossible to  help you until we don't know 1.) What HTML you are using your XPATH on 2.) How your automation class looks like (AT LEAST you should provide the find.by statement AND the used XPATH or something like that 3.) What tools you are using (which WebDriver etc.)